# Unable to limit

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE pc
INNER JOIN cams 
   ON cams.cam_id = pc.camuid 
SET 
    timestamp = NOW(),
    uid = @out_param:=uid
WHERE zone = 1 
  AND (unable = '0' OR unable IS NULL)
  AND (corrected_plate = ''  OR corrected_plate IS NULL)
  AND (timestamp IS NULL OR timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL @interval MINUTE)) 
LIMIT 1; 
SELECT @out_param;
```

I am unable to run that query as I have a `LIMIT`clause in a join query.  I cannot figure out how to spread it out into a subquery while maintaining performance.  I need this query to be as fast as possible, and the optimiser of MySQL has not provided much help so far.

**This is the error obtained from MySQL**, as the above is not allowed: `Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT`

Comment: You should post any relevant errors you encounter

Comment: This is the error obtained from MySQL, as the above is not allowed: `Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT`

Comment: You are using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` clause. So from the pc records matching your criteria you are trying to pick one arbitrarily and update it?

Comment: Yes correct, I am trying to pick one arbitrarily

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

You should tell us what you want to do so we can help you. Right now you are trying to do something is  just wrong.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - What I am trying to do is pick a row and set the `timestamp` on this particular row, and return the `uid` of that respective row. The row is selected based on a number of conditions spanning fields in another table

Comment: Any random row matching the conditions? do `PC`  has any primary key ?

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @Hackerman - ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used in an UPDATE statement with a join. Hence my problem

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - The PK is `uid`. I can also just choose the row with the smallest uid, so it does not have to be arbitrary.

Comment: You need to store the result of `select cam_id from pc ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, so there you have your random candidate and in your update instead of limit 1 you just add an extra condition in your where statement.

Comment: @Hackerman - Could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a subquery to decide which uid update.

```
UPDATE PC
SET timestamp = NOW(),
   uid = @out_param:=uid
WHERE uid = (SELECT uid
             FROM ( SELECT * FROM pc ) as pc2
             INNER JOIN cams 
                ON cams.cam_id = pc2.camuid 
             WHERE zone = 1 
               AND (unable = '0' OR unable IS NULL)
               AND (corrected_plate = ''  OR corrected_plate IS NULL)
               AND (timestamp IS NULL OR timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL @interval MINUTE)) 
             ORDER BY uid -- optional
             LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'pc' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Typical MySQL issue. Try replacing `FROM pc as pc2` by `FROM (select * from pc) as pc2`. Looks ridiculous, but is usually the way to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that slow it down even more though?

Comment: Query is still running (been around 5 minutes so far). The solution I'm after has to execute in milliseconds, which I can achieve without the limit part (but I need to only return 1 row)

Comment: You probably havent set the proper index yet. If you run only the subquery `SELECT uid ...` how long take?

Comment: Unfortunately the table `pc` has around 10 million records, so a query in that format is going to take long for sure.

Comment: I have table with 100 millions rows and query work ok, you need create the proper index but that is a different question. 
 Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and
 
 [**How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Without the subquery and without the limit 1 part, it takes 0.043 seconds to execute. With the query as it is above, it takes around 20 minutes.

Comment: I told you to test the subquery. Check the index and execution plan. Show us what index have you created. But again that is a different question. I already solve your `LIMIT` question so just create a new one so we can handle the perfomance issue. But be ready to include the explain plan

Comment: Accepted as it might solve someone else's problem. In my case the performance was too slow, even though I optimised

Comment: I told you. We solve performance question every day. But we need the explain plan to know where to improve. Just ask another question and provide the relevant information.